# É possível altera o formato do arquivo json?

Tags: angularjs, json, web-service, rest

Eu tenho um código que me gera um arquivo Json neste formato:

```html
[
  {
    "$id": "1",
    "poule": 73,
    "idusuario": 4,
    "vendedor": "ITAMAR SOUZA",
    "total": 50.00,
    "datajogo": "2016-01-19T00:00:00",
    "terminal": "(11)985590116",
    "empresa": "SANTIAGO - LOJA 01",
    "nsu": 73
  }
]
```

Eu gostaria de escrever a saída desta forma:

```html
{
"venda":
[
  {
    "$id": "1",
    "poule": 73,
    "idusuario": 4,
    "vendedor": "ITAMAR SOUZA",
    "total": 50.00,
    "datajogo": "2016-01-19T00:00:00",
    "terminal": "(11)985590116",
    "empresa": "SANTIAGO - LOJA 01",
    "nsu": 73
  }
 ]
}
```

Este é o código:

```html
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("consulta/ListarUltimoJogosRalizado/{idusuario}")]
        public HttpResponseMessage ListarTodosJogosAtivos(int idusuario)
        {
            try
            {
                var tTabela = new  JogoAplicacao();
                var listar = tTabela.ListarPoId(idusuario);
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, listar.ToArray());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Se o código for alterado para :

```html
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new  { jogo = listar.ToArray() });
```

o retorno fica assim:

```html
{
  "$id": "1",
  "venda": [
    {
      "$id": "2",
    "poule": 73,
    "idusuario": 4,
    "vendedor": "ITAMAR SOUZA",
    "total": 50.00,
    "datajogo": "2016-01-19T00:00:00",
    "terminal": "(11)985590116",
    "empresa": "SANTIAGO - LOJA 01",
    "nsu": 73
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segue uma solução:

```
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new { $id = 1, venda = listar.ToArray() } );
```

Ps: Postei do celular então não consigo testar a sintaxe mas é basicamente isso

Comment: muito válido a ajuda, mais veja que o $id do Json se repete e altera o número, esta correto assim ou tem outra forma de fazer?

Comment: atualizei a resposta

Comment: agradeço a ajuda, mais a minha ideia era retira este $id que aparece antes de venda : na minha pergunta veja como fica logo no final dela

Comment: adicione a seguinte tinha no seu `webapi.config.cs` : var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
        json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling =
            Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.None;

Comment: Genial a sua resposta!  imensamente agradecido!